# Scaling with Apache Spark/Apache Flink

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I plan an application that reads from Apache Kafka and after (potentially time-consuming) processing saves data to a database.

My case are messages, not streams, but for scalability I'm thinking about plugging this into Spark or Flink, but can't grasp how these scale: should my app, when a part of Spark/Flink, read some data from Kafka and then exit or keep reading continuously?

How will then Spark/Flink decide they must spawn more instances of my app to improve throughput?

Thanks!

Comment: Spark has Dynamic Allocation, it will create new executors when - as far as I remember - microbatch duration will come close to microbatch interval

Comment: I'm new to both of these - how my app should behave? should it just read once from Kafka and exit? How would Spark/Flink know it needs to create new jobs to read if there is more data in the queue?

Comment: Just create streaming job, Spark will scale number of executors automatically

Comment: I don't know Flink, so I don't want to write about it, but - AFAIK - it also has some automatic scaling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Apache Flink you can define the parallelism of the operations by setting the  `env.setParallelism(#parallelism)` to make all operators run with `#parallelism` parallel instances, or even you can define/override it per operator such as `dataStream.map(...).setParallelism(#parallelism);`.

For more info Check Flink docs https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/parallel.html.

Regarding reading from Kafa you can define the parallel receivers (same group) to scale up/down with the Kafka topic partitions : `env.addSource(kafkaConsumer).setParallelism(#topicPartitions)`

Check Kafka documentation for more info about Kafka topic and partitions and consumer group : https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/.

Note that if you don't specify the parallelism level inside the Flink program and you deploy it on local Flink cluster. The value of `parallelism.default` parameter inside the configs file `flinkDir/conf/flink-conf.yaml` will be used. Unless you specify it by the `-p` like  `./bin/flink run  .... -p #parallelism`. check [Flink cli options](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.7/cli.html).

Comment: Thanks, Ehab, I created a job via 'flink run' in cmdline, but should i run this on every server, or Flink somehow will take care of 'distributing' this job?
i'm interested in parallelism of jobs, not operators, so I guess this can be solved by Task Slots?

Comment: @estoy you just specify the degree of parallelism for the operators and Flink takes care of the rest.  The program code is converted to dataflow graph of chained subtasks.  check [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/concepts/runtime.html) for more details.  what do you mean by increasing parallelism of jobs?

Comment: what i want to ensure is this: one document posted to kafka-> one flink job processes it. two documents posted to kafa-> two flink jobs process them in parallel. without the second waiting for the first to finish

Comment: Ok, so if you set the right parallelism level of the operators inside you Flink program you can achieve that. If you have a concrete program I can check it for you.

Comment: thank you! - i posted the job code here https://pastebin.com/3Agk1pH3 
it's a single map() operation, which might be lenghty. the thing is, i'm new to flink and can't get my head around how it works - e.g. should i only run bin/flink run -c jobClass once for the cluster? 
right now with this code and taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 5, jobs posted to kafka are still processed sequentially, not in parallel, as i would've thought

Comment: Since you did not specify the parallelism level in you program.  Try to update the value of `parallelism.default` parameter inside the configs file `flinkDir/conf/flink-conf.yaml`.   or by 'bin/flink run -c jobClass -p 5`  Also answer is updated.

Comment: i played with what you suggested and jobs seem to run in parallel :D thanks a lot